# Button with Icon Issue in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Regards,I am having One issue. I am working on Button with Icon. But My icon is as Large in height as that of Button. But i want that icon should be smaller than that of button height so that there will be some sufficient space between them,it looks pretty. Here is my code for button.

```
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@layout/rbutton"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/things"
        android:text="OK"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
```

I am in hurry,So please help me to solve out the problem.If there is any tag or something then please tell me. Thanks

Comment: Its probably just a language issue, but your question seems a bit rude.

Comment: Sorry,What do you mean ?

Comment: Dear Avin, @HalR is probably talking with regards to your last line. You could have been a bit more polite while asking your question. :).

Comment: No,I am talking politely. But i am in hurry so may be you find it rude or something. Pardon Mr. HalR,i didn't mean anything wrong. Actually i have to submit my project today,so i am in hurry.

Comment: Indeed, when I first read it I thought it sounded a little rude, as well. Most developers are in a hurry as we all have deadlines. Members on SO generally do our best to give a workable answer in an efficient manner, provided we get feedback needed from the OP. So saying you are in a hurry isn't necessary and makes it sound as though you need top priority. As @HalR said, probably a language issue but just my thoughts

Comment: I am Sorry.Actually I didn't mean anything wrong.

Comment: I was just pointing out something that you would likely not be aware due to a language issue, and I would hate to have people not answer it because of that.  I'm glad you are getting many responses.

Comment: Ok,It was my mistake. Thank you for telling me and i resolved out with the problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an ImageButton instead of a Button, since it provides you better options to handle this kind of requirements you need, for example:

```
   <ImageButton 
            android:id = "@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_width="127dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_go_fb"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"        
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/your_icon"/>
```

**In the scaleType tag you can set 7 different values**: *center, centerCrop,centerInside,fitCenter,fitEnd,fitStart,fitXY* to get different scales to fit the image into the imageButton.

**Edit:** 
If you are looking for implementing a complex button, then I'll advice you to implement a layout and add an onClickListener to it, I think RelativeLayout is the better solution,
for an Image + Text: you could have something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout 
            android:id = "@+id/wrapper1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="65dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:id = "@+id/my_Iview"
                android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
                android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src = "@drawable/my_image"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
                android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/my_Iview"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
               android:layout_marginLeft = "8dip"
                android:text = "some_text"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Then in the activity you set the onClickListener for the layout as simple as you do it for a button.

GoodLuck

Comment: Thank you mr. Daniel.Actually i have text as well,i just wonder if it works ?

Comment: In that case I'd go for a layout instead of a button

Comment: Ok,I will try this as last option.But if you have any other idea Daniel ?

Comment: Appreciate your quick response,i solved the problem with Mr.Chor's method. I will give try to this code may be in some other part of my Project. Thank you very much. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Simply change

```
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

instead of

```
 android:layout_height="35dp"
```

it will look Like this

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mr Dixit,I did it. Actually Button height gets smaller and icon both.but I want that icon should be smaller than that of button so that there can be some small space between them,if it is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to `icon should be smaller than that of button height so that there will be some sufficient space between them,it looks pretty` I think all you need is padding.

Eg: `android:padding="15dp"`

Comment: Yes,I tried Padding but When i adjust with padding then my text also get hidden to some extent half or full due to adjustment of paddng.

Comment: @AvinSharma Then I suggest you change the layout height to wrap_content. To better control the size of image you should actually provide each density an image, Eg: 24x24 for ldpi, 32x32 for mdpi, 48x48 for hdpi and 64x64 for xhdpi. This should be the recommended way, as opposed to specifying width and height explicitly

Comment: Yayy,,Man it Works. Thank you very much Mr. Chor Waichun. Cheers